# How to import Custom javascript and css files in Using laravel 6

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-6

I'm starting out with Laravel which as at the time of this writing is 6.0. I need to import custom JS and CSS files in my project.

Form the file structure in Laravel 6, there is a js/ and /sass file in the resources folder. I have created a script.js and a style.css file right there.
I tried to call them using the code

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

and

```
    <link href='{{ asset('sass/style.css')}}'>
```

but my console log shows

```
    GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Is there a new way of calling these files in Laravel 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the function `asset()` will look for files in the public folder. Since laravel starts from the public folder.

Create new folders on public as `js` & `sass` then move you are files in new folders.

public folder host's assets such as images, JavaScript, and CSS. please check [laravel structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/structure#the-public-directory) for more information.

Having files In `resources/js` & `sass` folders should be compiled with [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) to public folder, you should try this when you learnt 80% percent of laravel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now understand plus I have tried the laravel mix.